# Target Single element with the same class name as multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Im trying to achieve a hover effect, which targets a single element but has the class name as multiple elements. for example i only want the hover effect to happen when you hover over that particular element. But the code to work if i hovered over the remaining elements, this is what i have so far..

```
$(".thumb-overlay-content").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').removeClass('animated rotateOut');
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').addClass('animated rotateIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').removeClass('animated rotateIn');
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').addClass('animated rotateOut');
});
```

thanks

Comment: You need a way to select that particular element.. give it another class, an id, maybe select it by index...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS alone to accomplish this: `.thumb-overlay-content:hover`

Comment: You have to add another attribute for parent elements, to know, which it is. F.e. data-id, or just id...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.hover` function in jquery. This allows you to specifically target the item that you hover over. Unlike the answers above you do not need to use the `.parent` function.

```
$(".thumb-overlay-content").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rotateOut').addClass('rotateIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rotateIn').addClass('rotateOut');
});
```

Also there is no need to remove the `.animated` class if you are just going to immediately add it back in.

See a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6WgL/1/)**

*On a side not, I'm not sure jquery is needed, if you adjust your CSS it could all be accomplished with a simple `.thumb-overlay-content:hover` class*

Comment: You could also be more specific with your classes so that you could just use `toggleClass` add/remove a single class to get the same effect

Answer (score 0):

You should use an identificator or a more precise query in your jQuery.

Add the `id` attribute to your object, and:

```
$("#myIdName").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').removeClass('animated rotateOut');
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').addClass('animated rotateIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').removeClass('animated rotateIn');
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').addClass('animated rotateOut');
});
```

Take a look at [jQUery selecto](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)r to build a more precise query

Comment: And chained calls/caching.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more context would be helpful, but have you tried toggleClass?

```
$(".thumb-overlay-content").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').toggleClass('rotateIn rotateOut');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent('.thumb-overlay-desc').toggleClass('rotateIn rotateOut');
});
```

Btw, $(this) already targets the triggering element, other elements with the same class name should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of your context, but you *should* just be able to remove the `'.thumb-overlay-desc'` from the `parent()` function.

I'm also not completely sure of your issue, it would help to see it in action. But try this:

```
$(".thumb-overlay-content").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('animated rotateOut').addClass('animated rotateIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('animated rotateIn').addClass('animated rotateOut');
});
```

I also combined the `removeClass()` and `addClass()` to the same line because there is no need to re-identify the selector, with jQuery you can stack functions.